# Rails association in concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport-concern

I am using concerns for my rails application. I've different kind of users so I have made a `loggable.rb` concern.

In my concern I have

```
included do 
        has_one :auth_info 
    end
```

because every of my user that will include the concern will have an association with auth_info table.

The problem is, what foreign keys I need to put in my auth_info table?

E.G

I've 3 kind of users:

1. customer
2. seller
3. visitor

If I had only customer, in my table scheme I would have put the field

```
id_customer
```

but in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) (and drop the concern):

```
class AuthInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loggable, polymorphic: true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :auth_info, as: :loggable
end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :auth_info, as: :loggable
end

class Visitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :auth_info, as: :loggable
end
```

Now you can retrieve:

```
customer.auth_info # The related AuthInfo object
AuthInfo.first.loggable # Returns a Customer, Seller or Visitor
```

You can use `rails g model AuthInfo loggable:references{polymorphic}` to create the model, or you can create the migration for the two columns by hand. See the documentation for more details.

Comment: what do you mean with "drop the concern". I've a lot of common method that will be easily shared between all the models this way

Comment: What I meant was that if your whole concern class was practically a one-liner, that you might as well remove the concern. But if you have more relevant code in there, then of course you can keep the concern, including the definition of the `has_one` relation, yes.

Comment: After re-rereading your question, perhaps my answer is not the best solution to your problem. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: your solution is right, but I have a problem. When I do ´customer.auth_info´ it gives me an error because the query search for customer_id and not loggable.id ! what can be the problem?

Comment: Did you use `polymorphic: true` in `AuthInfo` and did you perform the migrations to work with the polymorphic relation? AuthInfo needs two columns to work: `loggable_id` and `loggable_type`. See the docs.

Comment: I've done it. look here for the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728270/what-is-wrong-with-this-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 0):

Since user has roles 'customer', 'seller', 'visitor'.
Add a column called **role** to Users table. 
Add a column called **user_id** to auth_infos table.

```
class AuthInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :auth_info
end
```

you can do

```
 user = User.first
 user.auth_info
```

Now you a additional logic to your concerns.

Comment: It seems the exactly thing that I was looking to

Comment: I have quickly search for **role** in active record, but I  couldn't find anything... can you share with me how do you know this thing? just curiosity, and looking for improving my search skills

Comment: Hello @ciaoben, he is suggesting that you add a new column to your database table by creating a migration, detailed here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers. You will need to run something like "rails g migration add_role_to_users" to create the migration file. Then edit the "change" method adding in something like "add_column :users, :role, :string". Hope this helps

Comment: yes, create a column called 'role' in users table using rails migrations