# What is wrong with this polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have

```
class User::AuthInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "auth_infos"
    belongs_to :authenticable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and

```
class User::Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "customers"

    has_one :auth_info, as: :authenticable
end
```

I am expecting that by doing this:

```
User::Customer.last.auth_info
```

the output should be a record from `auth_info`. But I see the query is wrong:

```
SELECT  `auth_infos`.* FROM `auth_infos` WHERE `auth_infos`.`customer_id` = 8 LIMIT 1
```

My table has `authenticable_id` and `authenticable_type,` the fields that the docs tells me to create to make polymorphic work.

What is wrong? Why is it using `customer_id` instead of `authenticable_id`?

EDIT:

Here the schema of the two tables:

[image: auth_infos]

[image: customers]

EDIT:

I did omit one thing, because I thinked that it was not important, but it seems to cause the problem, on the Customer model I am using a concern:

```
include User::Loggable
```

Here is the content of the concercn:

```
module User::Loggable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_one :auth_info 
    end

    def login ip_address
        @session_ip = ip_address
        create_session_token
        self.save
    end

    def renew_session
        @session_token_expire = renew_session
    end

    def destroy_session
        self.session_token = nil
        self.session_token_expire = nil
        self.save
    end

    def verify_session! (token, ip)
        if (ip == session_ip && token = session_token && session_token_expire.to_i > Time.now.to_i)
            true
        else
            false
        end 
    end


    private 

    def new_token( string = "" )
      ...
    end

    def digest_token token
        ..
    end  

    def register_user
        a = User.new email_address: self.email_address, kind: self.class.name
        a.save
    end

    def create_session_token
        @session_token = digest_token(new_token())
        @session_token_expire = (Time.now + AUTHENTICATION[::Rails.env]["expiration"]["session"].hour.to_i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end

    def renew_session
        session_token_expire = (Time.now + AUTHENTICATION[::Rails.env]["expiration"]["session"] + 3.hour).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end

    module ClassMethods     
        def authenticated_account
            current_account ||= self.find_by_session_token() if CbsoltCore::App::Environment.account_session_token && CbsoltCore::App::Environment.account_session_token != ""

            # mettere parte API token
            current_account
        end
    end 
end
```

I've commended out the include for concern in my module, and it works. Why?

Comment: what is your actual table names? Instead of custom names provided?

Comment: the table name is actually the custom provided!!! But I 'vve changed to the default and deleted the custom ones. So the tables are ´user_auth_infos´ and ´user_customers´. But noting change.

Comment: Do you have authenticable_type and authenticable_id in 'user_auth_infos'? Can you edit your question and show me fields as per models?

Comment: @ChitrankSamaiya done it. take a look! thanks

Comment: All is looking good. Try to build record using associations and put ur updated code as well. I mean table_names are not required then remove them.

Comment: You can also remove namespaces to check, if it is working or not?

Comment: removing the namespaces require a lot of work, I need to delete the folders etc... But if I havo no choice i'll try

Comment: @ChitrankSamaiya read my new edit please

Comment: Hi Ciaben, This is was happening becoz it might be overriding your concern and using concerns asscociations.

Comment: f**k, f**k It is a my stupid mistake. As you can see in my concern I am including a ´:has_one :auth_info´ that causes the problem! I am so sorry. Sorry for your time!

Comment: @ChitrankSamaiya exactly, we were writing the same! Give this as an answer so at leat I can give you the green tick for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is overriding association including in customer model.

```
included do 
    has_one :auth_info, as: :authenticable
end
```

Either provide polymorphic association inside concern or in real model.